# Can toy/ dry clay be used as an alternative to grafting wax?

Tags: grafting

Can **toy/ dry clay** (clay we use to give kids to play) be used as an **alternative to grafting wax** or can it be used as a **grafting sealer**?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Since I didn't get an answer here, I thought to give it a try anyway. I grafted using toy clay as the grafting sealer or the grafting wax. As I was not quite sure how the was work with high rain fall, I used a polythene shade as well. I did two grafts. One was successful and other was not. The reason for the unsuccessful one was bad graft scion. The answer is YES, toy clay can be used as an alternative to graft wax.

Comment: I'm not convinced that two data points at a 50% success rate allows a reliable conclusion. At best, it can be asserted that it worked once.You never mention what kind of plant(s) you are grafting and under what conditions the grafted plants were kept. And "toy/dry clay" is not particularly descriptive of the composition of the material used. All of these things affect the outcome. But, hey, if it works for you, don't let me rain on your parade. I have no material proof that it doesn't work.

Comment: More detail as to methods, materials and species would be very helpful for other users. At the moment you've answered the question for yourself, but the purpose SE is to share knowledge and help everyone.